# Nextage ros bridge simulation issue

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi everyone,
I think this is not a question, but a suggestion.

I have been following rtmos tutorials, and I found an Issue with in the http://wiki.ros.org/rtmros_nextage/Tutorials/Operating%20Hiro%2C%20NEXTAGE%20OPEN "Running ROS process, operating via scripts and GUI.", and specifically, in the third part: "Run python script for interactive operation".

The point is that when I run a simulation with:

```
ipython -i `rospack find nextage_ros_bridge`/script/nextage.py
```

It always return error to connect with my simulation model.

At this point, I found the path to the *main.wrl* modelfile, so I satarted to use this in calls to *nextage.py* script by:

```
ipython -i `rospack find nextage_ros_bridge`/script/nextage.py -- --modelfile  /opt/ros/indigo/share/nextage_description/models/main.wrl
```

Checking the nextage.py script, I figured out what was happening, and is that modelfile hardcode does not exists on my system (I have installed all following tutorials).

Now I have changed the path to

```
 /opt/ros/indigo/share/nextage_description/models/main.wrl
```

and everything works as described in tutorials.

I have been reading how to suggest a change  but I am not sure how to proceed, so if anyone can explain me how to proceed or suggest this change himself I would be really thankful.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/263693/nextage-ros-bridge-simulation-issue/) by [CesarHoyosM](https://answers.ros.org/users/30733/cesarhoyosm/) on ROS Answers with karma: 25 on 2017-06-12

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Thanks for pointing that out. While I agree that particular error is annoying and could be confusing for novice users, all system should be working without significant issue despite the error message. I opened [a ticket on the devel repository](https://github.com/tork-a/rtmros_nextage/issues/337) to discuss any improvement.

---

Originally posted by [130s](https://answers.ros.org/users/875/130s/) with karma: 10937 on 2017-06-12

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [CesarHoyosM](https://answers.ros.org/users/30733/cesarhoyosm/) on 2017-06-12**:
Ok! Thanks for your quick answer! I am novice here as you said, but if I can do anything to help let me know.